# How can I merge Terraform state drift back into configuration files?

Tags: terraform

I have a Terraform script which provisions AWS infrastructure with (among other things) a set of security groups.

Over time, these security groups have had a bunch of extra IP ranges added through the AWS console, so there's a drift between the `.tf` files and the real-world state.

Running `terraform plan` shows these differences, and wants to roll back to Terraform's configured state.

What I'd like to achieve is to (programmatically) update the `.tf` files' security group definition to reflect these additional IP ranges, bringing Terraform up-to-date and (hopefully) increasing the chances it'll be used to manage state changes in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a pending feature in Terraform: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15608

In that issue there are linked two projects that can help:

https://github.com/dtan4/terraforming

https://gitlab.com/Nowaker/terraform-import-as-hcl